# Rails error ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I got this error:

[image]

code looks like this:

```
def save_as_template
  obj_attributes = self.attributes
  obj_attributes.delete("id")

  course = CourseTemplate.new(obj_attributes)
  course.start_date = nil
  course.active = false
  course.save
```

But I can't do this:

```
 self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
```

because then other things went wrong ... what can I do?

```
class CourseTemplate < CourseObject
  #self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :description
  validates_numericality_of :instant_questions, :check_questions,    :repeat_questions, :mindmail_interval, :mindmail_reminder_interval
  before_validation :before_validation_set_default_values


class CourseObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lecturer, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :lessons, ->{order "lessons.sort ASC"}, :dependent => :destroy

  validate :language_allowed

class Course < CourseObject

  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients, :join_table => :clients_courses # TODO c
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user_groups
```

Comment: How does your `CourseTemplate` model look like? What are its columns?

Comment: I've added coruse / course_object / course_template model

Comment: I think it's because `obj_attributes[:type] = 'Course'` but you don't have a class called `Course < CourseTemplate` try running rails console and run `Course.new.type` and check what the value is printed

Comment: where have you found that code? ... can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the  Just a guess: the obj_attributes hash still contains a value for the `inheritance_column`key - that must not be in the hash passed to `CourseTemplate.new`.
But you should `dup` the hash instead of removing it from the attributes hash - I'm not really sure but altering this hash directly may affect the object your calling `save_as_template` on.

Don't tamper with the inheritance_column. This is properly managed by active_record when you use the constructors for these objects.

```
  obj_attributes = self.attributes.dup
  obj_attributes.delete("id")
  obj_attributes.delete("inheritance_column")

  course = CourseTemplate.new(obj_attributes)
```

Comment: course_template and course_object are asolute the same they only differ in the type

Comment: Or you put them in the ssame class hierarchy

Comment: solved. I had to add `obj_attributes.delete("type")`